# AR Foundation - Control Image Tracked Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, instantiation, timeline

I am using AR Foundation and I want to control spawned prefab's timeline.
I am trying to create a simple AR app. Imagine I am tracking an image where I am spawning Tracked Image Prefab. Let's say this prefab is a model of a dragon with some fire effect on its timeline. And I want to control the prefabs timeline when it is instantiated by `AR Foundation`. For example, I want to play fire animation with a button click.

Can I put a listener on the prefab to trigger the timeline in Runtime? How can I do it, please? Is my assumption that I need somehow communicate with the instantiated prefab right?

This is the object and I want to trigger its timeline to play after a button is clicked.

[image]

This is the simple code with I wanted to control instantiated prefab's timeline.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class TimelineController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayableDirector playebleDirector;

    public void Play()
    {
        playebleDirector.Play();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get yoru question correctly, the first you need is something that "prevales" on the scene, if the dragon is created or no, like a Controller.
Your controller can, for example, be the responsible to spawn the dragon. When your dragon is spawned, store that reference (`GameObject dragon = Instantiate(dragonPrefab);`). It also can have your button reference.

With that you can add your dragons behaviour to the button like:

```
button.onClick.AddListener(() => { dragon.dragonSpitFire(); }); //with lambda function
button.onClick.AddListener(dragon.dragonSpitFire); //without lambda function
```

And inside your method "dragonSpitFire" you can put your timeline or animation Start method, like your timeline.Play();

Comment: Thank you Lotan, you definitely put me on the right track. I finally solved it with Events and Delegates.

Comment: Your're welcome Mathef! Remember to mark this answer as correct (the tick on the left side) if it helps so more people can find it faster :D

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with Events and Delegates. All initiated objects are subscribed to the event and trigger the function responsible for playing the timeline.